# How to include iLife with a NetInstall Image of Lion?

Tags: macos, osx-server, server.app, ilife, netboot

I've got a **NetBoot server** set up on Lion server that pushes several NetRestore and NetInstall images.

While I have a NetRestore image that already has iLife '11 on it, I want to have a NetInstall image that has iLife '11 as well. That way, I can do a reinstall of the OS and iLife without having to erase data.

I've found [this](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3251133?start=0&tstart=0) article that says adding some iLife packages to the workflow with the "Add Packages and Post Install Scripts" automator action, but the guy who answered did this with iLife '09, wasn't completely sure, and used the NetRestore option.

Is there a way to run iLife install scripts with a **NetInstall** image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A recipe for deploying iLife 11 using [DeployStudio](http://www.deploystudio.com) just rolled across my twitter stream, so almost all the credit here goes to [Steve Yuroff](http://twitter.com/swy/status/173138001696784384) for the recipe.

It is available on github and lists the package names and checksums for verifying the install.

- https://github.com/swy/iLife-11-InstaDMG-catalog/blob/master/iLife11.catalog

Comment: I've used DeployStudio in the past, but I didn't set it up. I'll try it out and see what happens. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: It is well worth evaluating instead or in addition to NetInstall. It's been a mainstay for me for years.